# Mongodb Client Connection TypeError NULL issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

Working on a simple nodejs express app using Mongodb.  I am getting a typeerror cannot read from null when I try to work with the connection object that is returned.  The connection object isn't null so I am not clear on what the error message is actually trying to point out.

the line of code that is generating the error is:

```
const silos = conn.db('toolkit').collection('silos')
```

I have a debug console.log right before that of:
   console.log("Connection: ",conn)

I am checking for an error on the connect callback and the error is null.  Prior to this issue I had an issue with the connection and username/authentication so I know the error checking works as before it was triggering on bad logins.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null
    at mongoClient.connect (/var/projects/drake/Routes/Silos.js:22:28)
    at err (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:415:14)
    at executeCallback         (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:25)
    at executeOperation (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:422:7)
    at MongoClient.connect (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at getSilos (/var/projects/drake/Routes/Silos.js:18:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/projects/drake/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

the console.log line generators this message:

```
Connection:  MongoClient {
```

Here is the code that I use for the Mongo connection.  This is in a file and the MongoClient object is exported that is used in other files to connect to the database.

```
const url = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}`
const opts = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    authMechanism: process.env.MONGO_MECH,
    authSource: process.env.MONGO_SRC,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
        password: process.env.MONGO_PWD
    }
}
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const objectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const mongo = new mongoClient(url,opts)

module.exports.mongoClient = mongo
```

Here is the where I pull in that code and call the connect.
Importing the code:

```
const { mongoClient } = require('../mongo')
```

Using the imported code:

```
mongoClient.connect( (err, conn) => {
        if (err) err(res,err, "Database Connection Error", 500)
        console.log("Connection: ",conn)
        const silos = conn.db('toolkit').collection('silos')
```

this last line is the one that gives the error.

Results of the console.log

```
Connection:  MongoClient {
```

Answer (score 0):

One common cause of this is when you try to interact with the mongodb server before a connection is actually made. I might be wrong but I suspect you might be calling your db operations in the wrong order. To avoid this, make sure you have actually successfully connected to the mongodb server before running queries on the collection. If you are using mongoose, then

```
mongoose.connect('/a/valid/mongo/uri')
```

will make

```
mongoose.connection
```

a valid object that can be interacted with.

Could you please update your question with your connection handling code?

Comment: Not using Mongoose, but just the mongodb directly.  I have all the code for making the MongoClient and the connection in another file that exports the MongoClient that I use in this file to call connect on it.  This error occurs within the callback of that function which should return an error object and a mongoclient connection object.  the connection object console.logs as a MongoClient object, but calling the db function on that object gives me the error that the function can't be called on object null.  I check for an error and the error object is null. I added the mongo code.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what this was about.

I appreciate the feedback that I got to this.

I spent a weekend rewriting the code from scratch and it worked this time.  I did the same thing I believe.  There must of been a typo that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I want to share my experiences with this problem. I was using Mongoose to make the connection but it would crash on either a "replica set" or an "auth error". Eventually I decided to move to MongoClient, just like you did. This is because ["Mongoose will not throw any errors by default if you use a model without connecting."](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Moving to Mongo the connection error also returned 'null'. I searched and searched and tried several things, including copying your code and adding the 'auth' option, etc. I eventually switched back to Mongoose (though that shouldn't matter for what solved it for me) and did this:

1. Create a new user with ReadWrite abilities (didn't help immediately but is *definitely* needed, since it gave an error when deploying to Heroku without the correct 'new' user.). I now have *two* users in my MongoDB account.
2. Add the following to my (Mongoose) Schema:

```
///Already had this:
let testSchema = new Schema {
      foo: String,
      bar: Number
      }

///Added:
 ,{
        bufferCommands: false,
        autoCreate: false
    });
```

3. Since the DB was still empty I added the following code after creating the model.

```
///Already had this:
let Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

///Added:
Test.createCollection();
```

I believe it then initiated the collection 'for real'. In the mongo shell I know that a collection is not visible until there is an item in there. Now that the app.js didn't crash upon starting I managed to add a document to the database using a form in my HTML and it worked. I now have a working DB connected to my app. Hope this could help anyone also landing on this page.